# How to parse JSON string with list of the same objects but with different names?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft JSON.NET with .NET 4.6.1.
I was hoping that this library is "smart" enough to distinguish the same data types and automatically convert them to a collection. [There's the JSON](http://pastebin.com/SQtJqXL6). I was hoping to get all "Index" properties into an array or list.
Is there any way to do that properly? [Here are classes](http://pastebin.com/QN5V8eyZ) that I was trying to get it working with.

Comment: :) so, what's holding you back from doing it?

Comment: @Candide my lack of knowledge, hence the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if there is way to automatically do what  you want to do but you can use JSON-to-LINQ to achieve what you want.

The idea is to get the "history" node from your json content and then extract all the first childs of your "indexXXX" sub nodes. Once you have the sub nodes, you can go with the automatic deserializer.

```
var data          = JObject.Parse(json);
var historyItems  = from d in data["history"] select d.First;

foreach(var h  in historyItems)
{
    var history = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Index>(h.ToString());

    Console.Out.WriteLine("History : {0}, {1}, {2}", history.Pl, history.PlDesc, history.En);
}
```